# canvas drawImage() is not rendering properly after installing React v18

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I'm trying to have an image upload render onto a canvas. The canvas is not rendering properly with drawImage(). The problem is that sometimes it does render after a long time and the image stays on the canvas, but usually it only renders for a split second, if at all, before it disappears.

As you can see in the code below, I've logged every step of the image upload to the canvas rendering. The image data shows up at each step, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Also, this was working fine before updating to React v.18.

**This is the File Reader component:**

```
export default function FileInput(props) {
const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
const fileInput = useRef(null);
    

const handleImageSelection = (event) => {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            setSrc(e.target.result);
            console.log('loadfilereader');
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    useEffect((event) => {
        if (src) {
            console.log(src);
            props.selectImage(src);
        }
    }, [src, props]);
    
    const openFileInput = () => {
        fileInput.current.click();
        console.log('fileinput');
    };
}
```

**This is the Canvas component:**

```
export default function Canvas() {
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
const [canvasHeight, setCanvasHeight] = React.useState(null);
const ctx = useRef(null);
const [canvasImage, setCanvasImage] = React.useState(null);
   

useEffect(() => {

        if (canvasRef.current) {
            ctx.current = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
            console.log('canvasRef context rendered')
        }

        image = new Image();
        image.src = `${canvasImage}`;
        console.log(`canvasImage:`, canvasImage);
        image.onload = () => {
            var ratio = image.naturalWidth / image.naturalHeight;
            var imageWidth = canvasWidth;
            var imageHeight = imageWidth / ratio;
            setCanvasHeight(imageHeight);
            ctx.current.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
            console.log('photo has been drawn on canvas')
        };
    }, [canvasImage, size.width, canvasWidth])
    }
}
```